# Как подсчитать период(мощность) генератора псевдослучайных чисел – random?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как подсчитать период(мощность) генератора псевдослучайных чисел – random? Выдается ошибка памяти.

```
import random
mass = []

def py_random():
    mass.append(random.random())
    for i in range(1, 100000000):
        mass.append(random.random())
        if mass[i] == mass[0]:
            return i
print(py_random())
```

Comment: А зачем вы их все в список собираете?

Comment: Прочитать исходный код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def py_random():
    n = random.random()
    i = 0
    while True:
        n0 = random.random()
        if n0 == n: return i
        i += 1
```

Comment: жду уже минут 15, так и должно быть? (нет терпения, сорри)

Comment: Маловато ждёте, там период 2^19937-1

Comment: хорошо, подождем)

Comment: Вы представляете себе порядок этого числа?

Comment: я могу представить)

Comment: через сколько лет дождетесь сообщите D:

Comment: @Yakov,  не доживете

Comment: @vp_arth Откуда у вас это значение ( 2^19937-1)? можно источник

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: @LoveOnlyPython как прогресс? (:

Comment: @Danis зашибись)

Comment: @LoveOnlyPython а теперь?

Comment: @Danis неделю назад получил ответ)) примерно такой 2^19937-1